# A missing data type

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working on this predifend dataset in R called mtcars. The head of this dataset looks like:

```
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

on the left side there is the name of each car. how come it doesn't have data type such as num or factor ? how can I apply that on a simillar datset?

the structure is as :

```
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

where name of the cars doesn't appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you share, the name of car was read in and assign as rowname of the dataset. As `str()` only print out the summary of columns in dataset so it will not print any thing related with the row names.

So if you want to have the car name as a column just add a column:

```
mtcars_trial <- mtcars
mtcars_trial$carname <- rownames(mtcars)
```

Regard to comment:

```
# this will assign the column as rowname for dataset
rownames(mtcars_trial) <- mtcars_trial$carname 
# this will remove the carname column
mtcars_trial$carname <- NULL
```

Comment: cool. so, How do I apply that to cars dataset that I have which already has car's name as column. I don't want the cars name to appear as column. Is there a way I can do it in R ? or may excel.

Comment: I get an error doing this.Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed                                                       and the car name is factor : $ name  : Factor w/ 305 levels "amc ambassador brougham",..: 50 37 232 15 162 142 55 224 242 2 ...

Comment: As it stated, you are assign `rownames` by a column that have duplicated value which is not allow.

Comment: You're right. My dataset has duplicated vlaues. I'm just wondering since I won't be using the rownames, why wouldn't allow me to do so? Is there a way I could tell R to ignore any duplicate values ?

Comment: If you want to remove the rownames with carnames, just assign a sequence number to it is ok. For example: `rownames(mtcars_trial) <- c(1:32)`

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I removed duplicated values manually since my dataset is roughly small.

Comment: For filter duplicated in R you can used duplicated function with column name. 
Ex. `newDf <- df[!duplicated(df$colnames, ]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108681/discussion-between-sinh-nguyen-and-yahyaotaif).

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind this is that here, the names of cars are stored as rownames and NOT as a column in the data.frame.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Kunal Puri,

```
## values
mpg <- c(21.0, 21.0,22.8)
cyl <- c(6,6,4)
disp <- c(160,160,108)
hp <- c(110, 110, 93)
drat <- c(3.90,3.90,3.85)
wt <- c(2.620, 2.875, 2.320)
qsec <- c(16.46, 17.02,18061)
vs <- c(0,0,1)
am <- c(1,1,1)
gear <- c(4,4,4)
crab <- c(4,4,1)

## data.frame
df <- data.frame(mpg, cyl, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, vs, am, gear, crab, row.names = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710"))

## give a column name, take rownames values
df$cars <- rownames(df)

## row names removed
rownames(df) <- NULL

## rearranged df
df <- data.frame(df[12], df[1], df[2], df[3], df[4], df[5], df[6],df[7], df[8], df[9], df[10], df[11])
print(df)
```

output:

```
           cars  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt     qsec vs am gear crab
1     Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620    16.46  0  1    4    4
2 Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875    17.02  0  1    4    4
3    Datsun 710 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18061.00  1  1    4    1
```

Does it help?I guess it is the same thing as previous solution.